# NSURLSession Authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, nsurlsession

I tried to use the swift code found [here](https://gist.github.com/n8armstrong/5c5c828f1b82b0315e24) on the website found [here](https://hac.chicousd.org/), but the response is html code with the two errors: "You must enter a password!" and "You must enter a User name!" I am new to NSURLSession and tried to change the string for authentication but nothing worked to change the response. Here is my code:

```
 let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
 let userPasswordString = "username@gmail.com:password"
 let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
 let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
 config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
 let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    var running = false
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://hac.chicousd.org/")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
            (let data, let response, let error) in
            if (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse) != nil {
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)
            }
            running = false
        }

        running = true
        task.resume()

        while running {
            print("waiting...")
            sleep(1)
        }
```

And this is in the console response:

```
<!-- Start Error box -->
<div id="errorContainer" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;">
<button id="portalCloseError" type="button" class="close"> &times;</button>
<span id="errorMessage" class="error" data-pw-error="You must enter a password!" data-username-error="You must enter a User Name!"></span>
</div> <!-- End Error box -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to sign in to a website: HTTP Authorization and form. Most website uses the later, more user-friendly login form. HTTP Authorization is only used when the website *expects* to interact with a user program (no, browsers don't count here).

Before you code, you need to scout the website for what form data it sends, as knowing is half the battle:

1. Visit [the school website](https://hac.chicousd.org/LoginParent.aspx?page=default.aspx) and press `Cmd + Opt + C` to open the Developer's Console.
2. Click the **Network** tab.
3. Do not close this console. Go back to the website and enter your username and password as usual.

Observe what data the page sends:

[image: Developer Console]

In plain text:

```
checkCookiesEnabled         true
checkMobileDevice           false
checkStandaloneMode         false
checkTabletDevice           false
portalAccountUsername       email
portalAccountPassword       password
portalAccountUsernameLabel
```

So the username is delivered in a field called `portalAccountUsername` and password in `portalAccountPassword`. The other fields may or may not be important.

And now you can write your code:

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://hac.chicousd.org/LoginParent.aspx")!

    // The form parameters
    let parameters = [
        "checkCookiesEnabled": "true",
        "checkMobileDevice": "false",
        "checkStandaloneMode": "false",
        "checkTabletDevice": "false",
        "portalAccountUsername": "username",
        "portalAccountPassword": "password"
    ]

    let bodyString = parameters
                        .map { $0 + "=" + $1 }
                        .joinWithSeparator("&")
                        .stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("empty data")
            return
        }

        // This is the HTML source of the landing page after login
        let html = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

For some reasons, I couldn't make the request until I [disabled App Transport Security](http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error). Maybe resources on that website come from non-HTTPS domains.

Comment: One of the best and well worked answers on stack overflow I've seen. It did work. I edited my question to add more detail because it was getting voted down, but it doesn't matter now, thank you.