# Swift Alamofire response to .jsp

Tags: swift, jsp, swift2, alamofire

I wanna log in to [this link](http://students.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/index.jsp)
My code is this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let username = "14-032"
    let password = "choi3704"
    let loginParameters = ["id": username as String, "pwd": password as String]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://students.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/index.jsp", parameters: loginParameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON{ response in switch response.result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
        print(response.objectForKey("type"))
    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error, \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I got

> Request failed with error, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 8." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 8.}

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38116022/nsurlsession-authentication) to see how to scout the website for info. You didn't use the correct URL andyou don't the `encoding: .JSON` either.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://students.ksa.hs.kr/scmanager/stuweb/loginProc.jsp", parameters: loginParameters)
    .responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):
            let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
            print(response.objectForKey("type"))
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error, \(error)")
            }
    }
```

A couple other notes:

- Please don't post real usernames and password to StackOverflow. There are bots that scan for these.
- Your school uses **unsecured** HTTP for a login site. They are asking to be hacked.